# amd platform w. integrated graphic no signal to monitor at boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, integrated-graphics

I am running in a very annoying problem. I just build a system with an Amd a10 (7800, FM2+) cpu on an Asus motherboard without a graphic card.
When I boot the pc after a night without current, the pc boot fine BUT I can't see anything on the screen. The monitor keeps blinking it's logo. I did check on the BIOS and set it to use the integrated graphics as main and tried again with no luck. The pc is correctly running because if I insert my password blindly I can reach the desktop and there i can press the power button on my case and get the usual "switch-off/reboot" dialog that ubuntu (15.10) shows.
Some other interesting points:

- I can't see the Asus logo at boot 99% of the times.
- The monitor is using a VGA cable (MB has DVI-D but the monitor can't use it)
- I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 but that shoudn't be an issue.

Any Idea? Since I can't see the bios' Asus Logo I think it's a bios/hardware issue and nothing to do with Ubuntu. Is there any possibility that the "Bios logo" issue is unrelated with the "no signal" issue when the OS is loaded? I'd like to see some logs about it but I think nothing is written somewhere. The annoying thing is also that I can't really test it by rebooting. It does happen all the time when I leave the pc off for some time, but not when I just switch off and on in 5 minutes. The fact that sometimes the electricity goes off during the night I'm not sure if it's relevant.

Edit tldr; list of the situation with more info:

1. MB is connected with a VGA cable to the monitor
2. MB has an integrated graphic card (AMD A10 cpu) and no external card
3. the lcd screen does not have issues with the resolution used but it's analogic, hence no possibility to use DVI (MB has only DVI-D)
4. OS is Ubuntu 15.10
5. Screen resolution is at the moment 1920x1080
6. I can't see the Asus Boot logo most of the times.
7. I can enter in the Bios even if I can't see the logo (F2 or Del, not sure)
8. There is some kind of signal issue, since when I blindly login in Ubuntu and then press the Switch on the pc, the screen "wakes up"
   and show me the desktop (with the "switch off/reboot" dialog of
   ubuntu)
9. It's not easy to reproduce. Once everything works, if I switch off and on, everything works fine (note: Boot logo might not
   appear.This isn't an issue imho)

Point 8. is the key. What does Ubuntu/ MB do when I press the switch on my pc case? The signal that is sent to the OS "wakes up" the screen or sends the right signals at least.

Comment: TBH it's not totally clear to me what you're seeing and what not. E.g. did you really see the BIOS setup. If you can use the BIOS setup, with an ASUS product, you'll most likely have options regarding the boot screen; did you try them? -- From a different perspective, your description regarding the MB -> monitor connection is not precise; how exactly are they connected -- that might contribute to the problem. And also you don't mention anything about screen resolution chosen and monitor type and/or its screen resolutions. Maybe you'll get better results if you edit your Q.

Comment: @ClassStacker I've added a list of points to make it clearer.

Comment: If the MB has only DVI-D, then how do you use a VGA cable to connect to the monitor?

Comment: @ClassStacker I meant only a -D and not a -I. The DVI is only of type D. There is a VGA as well of course.

Comment: I can't see how point 8 would be the key, and I don't agree that the BIOS logo not appearing is not an issue. Throughout the boot process, the graphics card will be set to several different modes, first by the BIOS, then by the boot loader, finally by the operating system. The fact that the behaviour depends on how long the PC was switched off is not a good sign. The first thing you must make sure is that the BIOS has a version which flawlessly supports your A10 -- sometimes it must be the latest version, sometimes it shouldn't be the latest version.

Comment: @ClassStacker thanks for the tip. I will check the bios version. I have seen  on other pcs that sometimes you can't see the boot logo just because the monitor was slow in switching between resolutions or just on/off. That's why I think it's not an issue. I still believe point 8 reveal a lot about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but I answer in case someone else have a similar issue.

My monitor is "broken". Somehow the electronics can't always pick up the signals from any pc and show the screen. That's why sometimes a reboot was enough, sometimes a blind login.

I did test the monitor with another computer and had the same issue. A new Monitor with the first computer also worked flawlessly.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes I did try it with another monitor/pc. I've updated my answer.